# Nextjs send data (title of page) to component

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

I am trying to set custom title for each page in my next.js project.

Let's say this is my simple Layout

```
const MainLayout = props => {

  return (
    <Layout style={{ minHeight: "100vh" }}>
      <Head>
        <title>I AM TITLE</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <meta charSet="utf-8" />
      </Head>
      <Layout>
        <Content>{props.children}</Content>
        <FooterView />
      </Layout>
    </Layout>
  );
};

export default withTranslation('common')(MainLayout)
```

And login page.

```
import MainLayout from "../../components/layout/Layout";

class NormalLoginForm extends React.Component {

  render() {
    const { getFieldDecorator } = this.props.form;
    return (
      <MainLayout>
        // LOGIN FORM
      </MainLayout>
    );
  }
}

const WrappedNormalLoginForm = Form.create({ name: "normal_login" })(
  NormalLoginForm
);

export default WrappedNormalLoginForm;
```

I just can't find the way (i am still new into this) how to send title from login page to layout like a variable. Thank you for any help.

Comment: have you tried sending props to `<MainLayout pageTitile="Title" />` and use `props.pageTitle` in `MainLayout` component to display the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going to want to pass in the title as a prop.

```
<MainLayout title='Login Page'>
  // LOGIN FORM
</MainLayout>
```

```
<title>{props.title}</title>
```

You can also pass in a title as a dynamic variable:

```
<MainLayout title={loginPageTitle}>
  // LOGIN FORM
</MainLayout>
```